# some bug of scikit learn auc function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

Here is the code and output, I think from the output, it mean when fpr is 0, tpr is 0, this is correct as the prediction results marks everything to be 0.

But the output also said, when fpr is 1, tpr is also 1. I think it is not correct, since the predictor never predict something to be positive (label to be `1`), so how could the fpr (= # of correct prediction of 1/total # of 1) and tpr (= # of prediction of 1 / total # of 0) both to be 1?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred)
print fpr
print tpr
print thresholds
print metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

**Output**,

```
[ 0.  1.]
[ 0.  1.]
[1 0]
0.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two illustrations would give you a better understanding of how the *FPR* and *TPR* get computed.

***Case-1:***

```
y    = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
#                                          -^- see the change here
```

*True Positive = 0 
 
False Positive = 0 

True Negative  = 9 

False Negative = 1*

*True Positive Ratio, (tpr) = True Positive/(True Positive + False Negative)*
Therefore, *tpr = 0/(0+1) = 0.*

*False Positive Ratio, (fpr) = False Positive/(False Positive + True Negative)*
Therefore, *fpr = 0/(0+9) = 0.*

```
#Output:

fpr → [ 0.  1.]
tpr → [ 0.  1.]
```

***Case-2:***

```
y    = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
#                                          -^- see the change here
```

*True Positive = 1 
 
False Positive = 0 

True Negative  = 9 

False Negative = 0*

*True Positive Ratio, (tpr) = True Positive/(True Positive + False Negative)*
Therefore, *tpr = 1/(1+0) = 1.*

*False Positive Ratio, (fpr) = False Positive/(False Positive + True Negative)*
Therefore, *fpr = 0/(0+9) = 0.*

```
#Output:

fpr → [ 0.  1.]
tpr → [ 1.  1.]
```

---

**Note:**

According to the [`roc_curve documentation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html), it is clearly stated that thresholds[0] represents no instances being predicted and is arbitrarily set to `max(pred)+1`.
[Here, 2 for binary classification task]

This becomes valid when the `fpr` and `tpr` when calculated becomes a fraction and cannot be quantified to 0 or 1. Hence, the `threshold` varies from 0, 1, 2.
For eg, when the last 2 values of `pred` array become 1, you get 3 values for threshold as `fpr` and `tpr` become fractional values.

But in our case, both `fpr` and `tpr` had been either of 0 or 1 and hence there wasn't any need for a third value of the `threshold`.

Also, the array elements in both `fpr` and `tpr` form an increasing sequence, i.e vary from  0 →1 and must satisfy a shape >= 2. Therefore, it is mandatory to have both 0's and 1's in the array as the starting and terminal values.

Incase of fractional values of `fpr` and `tpr`, the middle column would contain these values enclosed by 0 and 1 on either side of the array.

Comment: Thanks Nickil for the patience of illustrating how fpr and tpr are calculated. Actually I understand those and my question is where does tpr 1 and fpr 1 comes from? For example, in your case 1, there is pair (1) when tpr is 0, fpr is 0, and (2) when tpr is 1, fpr is 1. Wondering where does the 1 comes from, as I think the predictor always predict false, there is no positive prediction, so should not be 1. If you could clarify, it will be great.

Comment: Another though is, there is a routine of roc to be fixed at range [0, 1], so scikit learn makes the final trp and fpr pair -- it does not mean the score/target data could form 1/1 case, just to make it mathematically elegant.  Your comments and guidance is appreciated. :)

Comment: And in your 2nd example, I am wondering why not have another prediction threshold, like `fpr -> [0, 0, 1]` and `tpr -> [0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: @LinMa, I tried answering most, if not all of your queries. Please have a look at it and see if you are able to reckon with it.

Comment: Thanks Nickil, appreciate for your patience and vote up. In your first example, when tpr is 1, fpr is also 1. My understanding is, since we never predict anything to be positive (value of 1), so when tpr is 1 and fpr is 1 is only for roc routine we need 1/1 as final value pair for tpr and fpr, correct?

Comment: And another confusion is, for threshold[i], it means when predicted value >= threshold[i], related tpr and fpr is tpr[i] and fpr[i], correct? If so, I think the way define threshold from scikit learn is still confusing, since in your first example, when threshold[0] is 1, tpr[0] and fpr[0] are both 0, but actually we never predict anything which is >=1, I am not sure if tpr[0] and fpr[0] to be both value of 0 is also another arbitrary defined routine by scikit learn?

Comment: Actually the thresholds are calculated in ascending order and returned in the descending order of their values so as to align with the `tpr` and `fpr`.And yes, the reason for limiting the value of `i` to the number of class-labels(*here, 2*) is to plot the ROC curve by looping over their elements respectively.

Comment: Thanks Nickil, vote up for your reply. When I draw ROC, the way I did is, sort confidence score (normally between 0 and 1) from higher to lower, choose threshold according to confidence score, I can pick-up one threshold for one confidence score for granularity, or I can pick-up one threshold for multiple confidence score if there are too many confidence score values. So, in the process, I did, the threshold should be in descending order (when value in x-axis increase, it reflects to lower confidence score, which has more % of false positive).

Comment: (cont'd), you mentioned "the thresholds are calculated in ascending order and returned in the descending order of their values so as to align with the tpr and fpr", I might be lost here, but I think calculating in descending order for threshold is a natural way? Why we need order twice? If I mis-read anything, please feel free to correct me. Have a good weekend. :)

Comment: As quoted by the doc-page "*Since the thresholds are sorted from low to high values, they are reversed upon returning them to ensure they correspond to both fpr and tpr, which are sorted in reversed order during their calculation.*"

Comment: Thanks Nickil, vote up for your reply, I read the notes and I am confused why threshold needs reverse? is it because we provide target and scores in the order from negative (value of 1) to positive (value of 2)  `y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])` and `scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])`? It does not make sense to me since when draw fpr on x-axis, threshold should be from high to low, so sorting from high to low is more natural. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can open a new question if needed, I think my original question is almost answered.

Comment: I feel that would be better. You could also pose your queries on [*Cross Validated*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) where you would get a more theoretical perspective of the *under the hood* implementations regarding how the thresholds get calculated. +1 for your persistence in digging deep into the topic :-)